# How to map singe df col into multiple 'checkbox' cols

Tags: python

I'm trying to prep a csv for import into a survey tool from an exported csv from yet another tool. I need to map a singe column of values from one df into multiple columns to satisfy the checkbox of the other csv.

For example my starting df (df1) and target df (df2) look like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bob': [0,0,0], 'Jane': [0,0,0], 'Alice': [0,0,0]})
```

I've tried:

```
for value in df1["User"]:
    if value == "Bob":
        df2['Bob'] = 1
    elif value == "Jane":
        df2['Jane'] = 1
    elif value == "Alice":
        df2['Alice'] = 1
```

But I end up with a '1' in every row and column.

Result:

```
  Bob Jane Alice
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1
```

I'm trying to create:

```
  Bob Jane Alice
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is my first post, so any feedback on structuring a good question is also appreciated

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: added expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
pd.get_dummies(df1["User"])
```